# Create an LDAP Server on Windows Server 2012

Tags: active-directory, ldap, windows-server-2012, adldap, apache-directory

I want to create an LDAP server exactly like this
http://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/

I have already setup my LDAP on Windows Server. However, I still don't understand how to create an LDAP server, so that I can connect from Apache Directory Server on client PC.

Is there any step by step tutorial on how to create an LDAP Server with admin and users on Windows Server 2012?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Err, Active Directory *is* an LDAP server, and someone else's online test LDAP server isn't something you can install yourself. Maybe what you want is to copy the online server's contents into your AD? Unclear what you're asking, and off topic.

Comment: I'm sorry my english is not that good. Yes. I do already have setup a Active Directory or LDAP Server. What actually I mean is that I want to create a list of example user and admin just like the example online-test-server. 

I've already create a few admin but still failed to connect from Apache Directory Studio.

Comment: So your real problem is failure to connect. So either the host:port was wrong or your credentials were.

Comment: Yes. The thing is when I always successfully connected to the server when I chose 'No Authentication'(except I got error no Schema return). But when I use the credential that I already set then I got the error code 80.